# Efficient "Screenshots" of a View?

Tags: android

TL;DR: Since `getDrawingCache()` seems to trigger a complete redraw of a `View` when hardware acceleration is enabled, is there an alternative means of getting a `Bitmap` (or something along those lines) that avoids this, perhaps by reading data populated into a (hardware, software) layer when the `View` was last drawn?

---

Some background:

Android has had the ability to mirror the screen since Android 3.0, such as to an attached HDMI display. This can be used for presentations, but it means the audience sees the same thing as the presenter, which is not always ideal.

Android 4.2 added `Presentation`, to allow apps to put arbitrary stuff on the "second screen" (e.g., HDMI attached display). In this case, at times, it would be useful for the second screen to be showing *part* of what is on the main tablet's display. If you think of presentation software like Microsoft PowerPoint, LibreOffice Impress, and the like, in typical dual-screen setups, the audience sees the current presentation slide, while the presenter sees the current slide and a timer and speaker notes and...

For non-interactive content, like a PNG representing a slide, this is simply a matter of showing the same image in both screens (alongside other stuff on the primary screen).

However, for interactive content, like a `WebView`, it is sometimes difficult to do this sort of mirroring. For example, we have no good way of knowing when the content of a `WebView` might change, as it may do so based on stuff purely within the `WebView` itself (e.g., completion of AJAX calls), not something we do separately. And, even if we *did* know when the content of the `WebView` changed, we have no good way of getting some other `WebView` to render that same content.

So I figured I'd try to set up a `MirroringFrameLayout`, that would use `getDrawingCache()` to retrieve a `Bitmap` of the container's contents and deliver that to somebody who can render it on-screen (e.g., an `ImageView` shown in a `Presentation`).

However, with hardware acceleration enabled, `setDrawingCacheEnabled(true)` [is somewhat of a no-op](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setDrawingCacheEnabled%28boolean%29):

> Enabling the drawing cache is similar to setting a layer when hardware acceleration is turned off. When hardware acceleration is turned on, enabling the drawing cache has no effect on rendering because the system uses a different mechanism for acceleration which ignores the flag.

Calling `getDrawingCache()` in these cases forces a full `draw()` of the `View` to a bitmap-backed `Canvas`, rather than actually using a cache. Since `draw()` may be expensive, doing `draw()` frequently (say, triggered via `postOnAnimation()`) results in jank.

Hence, I am trying to determine if there is some other "drawing cache", beyond `getDrawingCache()`, that we can use with hardware acceleration enabled, that could be used to set up this mirroring, and that is more efficient. From what I can see, there is no such cache, as layers are effectively write-only from the standpoint of SDK apps. However, I am hoping that perhaps I am missing some solution.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: FYI, here is a GitHub repo containing my implementation: https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-layouts

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null)` but it will have the side effect of making that View slower to redraw every time it updates. It would be much more efficient to create a custom `ViewGroup` that draws your View on two Canvas (one for each screen.) You could also simply use a `ViewTreeObserver` and on every draw callback force your view to render on the second screen. I really recommend you don't try to abuse the drawing cache/layer type for such a use case.

Comment: Is it safe for me to render to a separate `Canvas` from `onDraw()` in the custom `ViewGroup`?

Comment: OK, so far, this seems to be working. Next project: getting the scaling right, since the mirror's size may not be identical to the original's size. To quote the "Zooming a View" training page, "Yay, math". :-) Thanks!

Comment: Hi, `Android has had the ability to mirror the screen since Android 3.0, such as to an attached HDMI display`. Does android has the ability to choose which layers to be mirrored to, say a virtual display ?