# Capturing View to Bitmap returns old image

Tags: android, android-layout, screenshot, android-view, android-bitmap

I need to capture View to a Bitmap. That's how I tried to do that:

```
private Bitmap getBitmapFromView1(View rootView) {
    Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(rootView.getWidth(),
        rootView.getHeight(),
        Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
    rootView.draw(c);
    return b;
}

private Bitmap getBitmapFromView2(View rootView) {
    rootView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(rootView.getDrawingCache());
    rootView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

    return bm;
}
```

I also tried to add `buildDrawingCache` and `destroyDrawingCache` to different places of the second function.

In `rootView` I have a `FrameLayout` with a `RecyclerView` inside. Sometimes after scrolling this `RecyclerView` and asking for a snapshot I get an image with older scroll position. I have this effect for both functions.

The interesting thing is that both work fine on the other screen, where `rootView` is `DrawerLayout` and it also contains `RecyclerView`

How to always get a fresh snapshot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disabling hardware acceleration for `RecyclerView` helped. I added it to `OnScrollListener` to avoid lags on scrolling. Seems to work.

```
private RecyclerView.OnScrollListener mSwitchAccelerationListener = new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
        super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);

        if (newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
            mRecyclerView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
        } else {
            mRecyclerView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
        }
    }
};
```

Useful post: [Efficient "Screenshots" of a View?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15551150/efficient-screenshots-of-a-view)